# Combining 2d matrices in numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I am new to python. I am trying to combine several matrices to a new matrix. For example: -

```
A = np.matrix([1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [9, 10, 11])
B = np.matrix([4], [8], [12])
C = np.matrix([13, 14])
D = np.matrix([15, 16])
```

at the moment im using: -

```
E = np.vstack((np.hstack(([A, B])), np.hstack((C, D))))
```

is there a more concise way in matlab i'd simply use: -
E = (A, B; C, D);

Many thanks

Comment: Not your question, but is there a particular reason you need to use a matrix, or are you just using it because that is what you used in MATLAB?  In python, numpy arrays are almost always preferred over matrices.

Comment: yes, thats the only reason, would you recommend using arrays?

Comment: Yes, definitely.  First, with Python 3.5 supporting matrix multiplication for arrays, arrays are pretty much always what people want in practice anyway.  There is rarely an advantage to using matrices.  Further, the python community has standardized on arrays, so most packages will return arrays, most expect arrays rather than matrices, and some functions even inside numpy will convert matrices to arrays.

Comment: Thats good to know, i'll change to arrays from now on. Thanks for the advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your matrices are missing outer brackets. If you define

```
A = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [9, 10, 11]])
B = np.matrix([[4], [8], [12]])
C = np.matrix([[13, 14]])
D = np.matrix([[15, 16]])
```

then

```
E = np.bmat('A,B;C,D')
```

yields

```
matrix([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15, 16]])
```

`np.bmat([[A,B],[C,D]])` also works. See [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bmat.html) for more on `numpy.bmat`.

Comment: `bmat` is more concise in how it is called, but functionally it is doing the same 2 levels of `concatenate`.  I expect the speed to be about the same.